# javascript variable pass into php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I get category id by js and want to use it to get category description.
when i am passing this  id using ajax into php variable its print correct output but when i try to put this id in get_description code ajax give 500 error and not return output why this happen please help me.

Below is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".-filter").click(function() {
        var js_var = this.id;

               $.ajax ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>category.php",
                    data: { val : js_var },
                    success: function( result    ) {               
                   $("#update").html(result);
            }

        });
    });
</script>

<div id="update">
<?php 
$cat_id = $_POST['val'];
echo $cat_id;
//echo term_description($cat_id,'category');
?>`enter code here
</div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please add you category.php file

Comment: @JohnVandivier i think this is his category.php file :)

Comment: what is `enter code here..you have commented or not?

Comment: check the console network..it will show you the url then right click and open it in new tab.check $cat_id is coming or not?

Comment: Hey @lalithkumar 'enter code here..' this is by mistake and i already delete this.

Yes cat id got in console but when uncomment this line'term_description($cat_id,'category');' its give 500 error in consol ajax url why this happened.

Comment: yes @JohnVandivier this is my category.php file i want output in same file.